# How to write data from spreadsheet to a Document?

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a spreadsheet with some data on it. i also have a document (which is like a template) with a table on it. i want to write specific data from the spreadsheet to specific cells of the the table in the document.

how do i access the table cells of the table in the document? here is my my guess and what i tried but dint succeed with. i would have to open the document by id, then access the table, and then access the relevant table cell. But i don't know how to go about this. any idea how to go about this?

Comment: All this is clearly explained in the documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table?hl=fr-FR   You can have access to any cell by its row/col index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceText(key, text)` on your app script.

In your document template, create the table as normal. In the table cell you have to create a key to be accessed via App Script. I use this format: '{%key_name%}'. To change this key via App Script you have to get the Active Section of the Document, and then use `replaceText()`.

Example:

### DOCUMENT TEMPLATE: Let's say I have the following table with 2 keys (name and phone):

### - Name   -  {%name%}   -

### - Phone  -  {%phone%}  -

Following code will replace the keys {%name%} and {%phone%}:

```
doc = DocumentApp.openById('your_document_id');
docBody = doc.getActiveSection();
docBody.replaceText('{%name%}', 'Jhon Smith');
docBody.replaceText('{%phone%}', '6325-2541');
doc.saveAndClose();
```

### And your table will look like this:

### - Name   -  Jhon Smith -

### - Phone  -  6325-2541  -